# How to add options in autocomplete contact search options?

Tags: relationships, fields, quicksearch, option

We have contacts with the same First and Last Names. It is hard to identify person when we use Quick Search or add relationships. And default options doesn't help to identify person aswell. Is there any way how can we add additional fields (e.g. Birth Date) into autocomplete contact search options?

We are using CiviCRM 4.7.14 and wordpress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add easily add predefined fields into the autocomplete results by selecting fields under "Autocomplete Contact Search" under "Settings - Search Preferences".

Adding the Birth Date will not be as easy. Technically you could add an additional option group value to the option group contact_autocomplete_options, but that will be pretty much experimenting at your own risk since this is supposed to be a reserved option group.